# HTML: Upload a file and stay on the page

Tags: html, cgi

I'm putting together a small HTML page that allows the user to upload files from his local device to the server. I'm using an approach that I found recommended in several places, which goes like this:

```
<FORM method="post" action="upload.py" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <INPUT type="file" name="rhythm-file">
   <INPUT type="submit">
</FORM>
```

This works, but it takes the user away from the page to `upload.py`. How can I stay on the page? I tried using `action="upload()"` to call a JavaScript function, with the idea of calling an asynchronous HTTP request from there, but then the browser tries to navigate to `cgi-bin/upload()`. I also considered modifying `upload.py` to redirect back to the previous page, but that just doesn't feel like the correct way to do it.

Comment: upload file with Ajax maybe? [jQuery ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: the common way to do it is to redirect back from the script to your page. like you said yourself. But a more elegant way would be to use ajax and php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AJAX for this. There are many libraries to help you upload files via AJAX.

Here are a few Jquery Plugins: https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-file-uploads/

Take a look at [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com), it has great documentation.

The file will be uploaded by dropzone asynchronously therefore the user will not be taken away from the page.